# TTK Treeview doesn't display subtrees

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I am using Python3 TTK Treeview to display a tree. But first, sub nodes are not indented and only first sublevel of the tree is visible. A parent sub node doesn't display its children.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

Win = Tk()

entries_tree = Treeview(Win, columns = ("Glyph", "Name"), show="tree")
entries_tree.column("#0", width = 20)
entries_tree.column("#1", width = 20)
entries_tree.pack()
#Test
Un = entries_tree.insert("", "end", values = ["X", "Un"])
Deux = entries_tree.insert("", "end", values = ["X", "Deux"])
Trois = entries_tree.insert(Un, "end", values = ["X", "Un Un"], open = True)
Quatre = entries_tree.insert(Un, "end", values = ["X", "Un Deux"])
Cinq = entries_tree.insert(Un, "end", values = ["X", "Un Trois"])
Six = entries_tree.insert(Trois, "end", values = ["X", "Un Un Un"])
Sept = entries_tree.insert(Trois, "end", values = ["X", "Un Un Deux"])

Win.mainloop()
```

Result :
First display
[image: Fist display]

First parent node expanded: Its first child (Trois) which is a parent node doesn't display the expansion possibility glyph, and children are not indented.

[image: First parent node expanded.]

Comment: Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If I am unable to see sub nodes from a sub node, it is because I forced width to be 20. So, the plus sign didn't show up. But the indentation problem still persists. How does Treeview manage indentation ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome. Please take time to append your question(s) into the main Question section. This will help other future users to learn from your question and meet stackoverflow's standards.

To allow you to see the directory, i.e. tree structure, you need to:

1. Widen column "#0". The default value of 20 is just wide enough to see 1 indicator and not its children.
2. Add the option *text = your_label_name* into the *.insert* method to identify the tree node.

You can also added the "open = True" in the .insert method for 'Un' to show the children of 'Un' at the onset.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

Win = Tk()

entries_tree = Treeview(Win, columns = ("Glyph", "Name"), show="tree")
entries_tree.column("#0", width = 120, stretch=0)
entries_tree.column("#1", width = 20, stretch=0)
entries_tree.pack()
#Test
Un = entries_tree.insert("", "end", text='Un', values = ["X", "Un"], open = True)
Deux = entries_tree.insert("", "end", text='Deux', values = ["X", "Deux"])
Trois = entries_tree.insert(Un, "end", text='Trois', values = ["X", "Un Un"], open = True)
Quatre = entries_tree.insert(Un, "end", text='Quatre', values = ["X", "Un Deux"])
Cinq = entries_tree.insert(Un, "end", text='Cinq', values = ["X", "Un Trois"])
Six = entries_tree.insert(Trois, "end", text='Six', values = ["X", "Un Un Un"])
Sept = entries_tree.insert(Trois, "end", text='Sept', values = ["X", "Un Un Deux"])

Win.mainloop()
```

[image: treeview]